How can I remove Dev Extreme React themes?
I installed Dev Extreme React into my project because I wanted to use their chart component. But now, I'm dealing with a bunch of extra classes that are showing up randomly on elements all over the project.
those kinda of classes:
.dx-theme-generic-typography, .dx-theme-generic-typography input, .dx-theme-generic-typography textarea {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Segoe UI, helvetica, verdana, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.35715;
}

I'm assuming this has to do with Dev Extreme React theme or something, even tho I never used any themes associated with Dev Extreme. I only imported and used the chart component.
I tried to google it but I didn't find anything useful. Even in their documentation, I do not find how to remove the theme only how to add a new one...
Can someone help please?

Just remove the links in the index.html. mainly with the rel=stylesheet

